# does Saved instance state on onCreate and onActivityCreated of a fragment differs?

Tags: android, fragment

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.savedInstanceState = savedInstance;
    }
@Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        try {
            Log.d("Equals?",savedInstanceState.equals(this.savedInstanceState));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("Equals?",savedInstanceState==this.savedInstanceState);
        }
    }
```

Will this always\never or only on some cases log true?

EDIT:
after seeing Henry's comment, lets address my question as if Intent has overriden its equals and it does compare those objects content, not by references...

Comment: I think your program should not rely on either possibility. Bundle does not override equals so you get true only if the same instance is passed as a parameter.

Comment: @Henry oh, didnt know that, but i mean are they trully equal as do they hold same extras and all data is the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**onCreate(Bundle)** called to do initial creation of the fragment.

**onActivityCreated(Bundle)** tells the fragment that its activity has completed its own Activity.onCreate().

so we can say that `Bundle savedInstanceState`  are same at both places.

for more visit

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

you wrote

```
@Override
    public void onCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        this.savedInstanceState = savedInstance;
    }
```

i do not understand which lifecycle mehod is `onCreated` i think it should be `onCreate` and the lines should be

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
....}
```

Comment: yeah, sorry that was a typo

Comment: its ok than!!!! Please read the links i have given, you will all clear, it always depends how you are processing life-cycle methods and what operations you are doing with them!!

Comment: does it explicitly document that these bundles are the same? it might be that the fragment has its own bundle and differs from the activities bundle...

Comment: i will check extensively and will be back if will have better explanation

Comment: it seems like it is the very same object